# R - Reshaping data frame and aggregate elements

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have a data frame like this

```
client  Product date
A        apple  May
B        grape  Jun
B        apple  Jun
C        apple  Jul
A        grape  Jul
```

And I would like to have this:

```
 client May Jun Jul
  A     1   0   1
  B     0   2   0
  C     0   0   1
```

That is, I would like to aggregate all products sold over months per client. I know that I try reshape and `data.table` but I can't figure out the best way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: With data.table or reshape2: `dcast(DT, client ~ date)` or with base R `with(DT, table(client, date))` (providing a slightly different object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(f~client+date,cbind(f=1,dat)))
  Jul Jun May
A   1   0   1
B   0   2   0
C   1   0   0
```

or you can do:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(dat[-2]))
  Jul Jun May
A   1   0   1
B   0   2   0
C   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Dplyr aswell

```
library(tidyverse)


client <- factor(c("A","B","B","C","A"))
product <- factor(c("apple", "grape", "apple", "apple", "grape"))
date <- factor(c("May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul"))

df <- data.frame(client=client,
                 product=product,
                 date=date)

df_sum <- df %>%
  group_by(client, date) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  spread(date, n, fill = 0)
```